# Replace numbers with images

Tags: jquery, html, web

So basically what I want to do is use jQuery to replace numbers with images.

I want to replace 5hr 53min with images so if there is a 5 then it will display 5.jpg, and the same thing with the 3 to replace that and display 3.jpg.

Here is an example of what I want to do:
http://pastehtml.com/view/c9of5gm15.html

Comment: What is the problem you encountered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('time').html(function(i, v){
    return v.replace(/(\d)/g, '<img src=$1.jpg />');
});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FtfkK/

Comment: i seem to have a small problem, im echoing a mysql query and it wont display.

Comment: @blaize9 - Can you post your HTML in a fiddle?

Comment: @blaize9 - Post the final HTML, not the PHP.

Comment: @blaize9 - You have to put your code in [document ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/): `$(function(){ /* all code here */ });`

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you I wont forget to give you some rep when i get 15 rep.

Answer (score 1):

```
var number = 5;
$('#myImage').attr('src', 'my_image_path/' + number + '.jpg');
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want to draw your numbers using a HTML canvas, and then create a data URL

See [Capture HTML Canvas as gif/jpg/png/pdf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923885/capture-html-canvas-as-gif-jpg-png-pdf)

Comment: Or, if you have the digits already, use @Shomz solution, of course.

Comment: Hmm i might use this in the future =D